# How to fetch subcollections in firestore without documentID in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to access a video subcollection part of my user's data document in the firestore database:

```
func fetchRecentVideos(ofArtist artistName: String) async -> [VideoModel] {
        let usersRef = db.collection("users")
        let userDocs = try! await usersRef.whereField("artistName", isEqualTo: artistName).getDocuments()
        
        if userDocs.count != 1 {
            print("snapshot.count was not 1!!!!")
        }
        
        userDocs.documents[0].collection("videos")
        
    }
```

I've seen plenty of posts and documentations showing how you can access subcollections by explicitly stating the path to the subcollection as such:

```
db.collection("users/\(documentIDofInterest)/videos")
```

This would've been the approach I'd use but I don't intend to use the documentID, so I must access the particular document first through a query using the whereField() method. However, this quickly is getting verbose. Also, I end up with a QueryDocumentSnapShot and I further need to transform it to be able to access the subcollection contained within it. Is there a simpler way I'm missing?

Also, I specifically don't want to use the documentID because I set Firestore to generate an AutoID for my documents for better security. But, as a consequence of that, am I making things difficult by doing that? Should I then rename my documents with perhaps the usernames or something similar?

Comment: You can use [collectionGroup()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) query but that'll fetch sub-collection from all the documents.

Comment: Yes, but that will fetch all documents as you state.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem, given that last comment. Either you can load documents from a specific subcollection by specifying the whole path to that subcollection, or you can load them from all subscollections with a given name by using a collection group query (as Dharmaraj mentioned). In both cases, you can use query condition to whittle down the number of documents that are retrieved.

Comment: I'll try and clarify what I meant: let's say we don't know the documentID of a particular document we wish to retrieve (we need it later on because we wish to retrieve the subcollection within that document). But, we store the username (unique) in the document, so I should be able to fetch the documentID by using the whereField(field: isEqualTo:) method to get a documentRef. Then, we can finally access the subcollection within that document, right? This approach (at first) seemed long winded to me, so I wanted to know if there was a simpler approach to doing the same.

Comment: Have you referred to this link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#swift

Comment: @Sandeep Vokkareni Yup, already did!

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#swift), which is clearly mentioned You can retrieve documents with one request by querying documents in a collection. For example, you can use where() to query for all of the documents that meet a certain condition, then use get() to retrieve the results which is the known solution for you. I don’t think there will be a better solution than this.